# Powershell + 7zip to batch extract and rename - getting "No files to process" message

Tags: powershell, 7zip, powershell-v6.0

**Edited:**

*Originally, my question was why the first piece of code wont work. the unzip action was working if I run it on it own on on single file outside the loop. but once I wrapped it round with loop, it won't work, and there was no red error either.*

Thansk @nemze , his/her answer inspired me to change the my code from:

```
$7ZipPath = "C:\7z\7za"
$zipFolderRoot = "Z:\long folder path\Test Folder\Unzip Test"
$zipOutPath = "Z:\long folder path\Test Folder\Unzip Test\Unzip"
$zipFilePassword = "TEST123"
ls -Path $zipFolderRoot -directory -Exclude Unzip

Foreach ($zipFolderChild in (ls -Path $zipFolderRoot -directory -Exclude Unzip))
{
$zipFile = '"$zipFolderChild"+"\"+"Data.zip"'
$command = "& $7ZipPath x -o'$zipOutPath' -y -p$zipFilePassword $zipFile"
iex $command
#file rename command that I have not written yet
}
```

To :

```
$7ZipPath = "C:\7z\7za"
$zipFolderRoot = "Z:\long folder path\Test Folder\Unzip Test"
$zipOutPath = "Z:\long folder path\Test Folder\Unzip Test\Unzip"
$zipFilePassword = "TEST123"
ls -Path $zipFolderRoot -directory -Exclude Unzip

Foreach ($zipFolderChild in (ls -Path $zipFolderRoot -directory -Exclude Unzip))
{
$zipFile = "$zipFolderChild"+"\"+"Data.zip"
$command = "& $7ZipPath x -o'$zipOutPath' -y -p$zipFilePassword ""$zipFile"""
iex $command
#file rename command that I have not written yet
}
```

By moving the `$zipFile` definition outside of the `ForEach` loop, this works!

I think my 2nd obstacle now move to getting my files renamed inside the loop.

What I am trying to achive:

- Data.xls from 20181001 folder rename to 20181001.xls
- Data.xls from 20181008 folder rename to 20181008.xls

The amended code is still reading `$zipFolderChild` as the full path, how can I extract the **folder name ONLY** instead?

**EDIT3:**

Trying to get the rename statment into the loop, but not sure how to get the `-NewName` argument work, `$zipFolderChild.Name.xls` clear doesn't work. Also tried:

```
$folder= $zipFolderChild.Name
#file rename command that I have not written yet
$rename = "-path", "$zipOutPath\Data.xls" ,"-NewName", "$folder.xls"
& Rename-Item @rename
```

inside the loop, not working either.

FINALLY WORKING:

```
$7ZipPath = "C:\7z\7za"
$zipFolderRoot = "Z:\long folder path\Test Folder\Unzip Test"
$zipOutPath = "Z:\long folder path\Test Folder\Unzip Test\Unzip"
$zipFilePassword = "TEST123"
ls -path $zipFolderRoot -directory -Exclude Unzip

Foreach ($zipFolderChild in (ls -path $zipFolderRoot -directory -Exclude Unzip))
{
$zipFile = "$zipFolderChild\Data.zip"
$cmd = "& $7ZipPath x -o'$zipOutPath' -y -p$zipFilePassword ""$zipFile"""
iex $cmd

$folder= $zipFolderChild.Name
$xlsFile = "$zipOutPath\Data.xls"
$NewName = "$zipOutPath\$folder.xls"
&  Rename-Item -Path "$zipOutPath\Data.xls" -NewName $NewName
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
$7ZipPath = "C:\7z\7za"
$zipFolderRoot = "Z:\long folder path\Test Folder\Unzip Test"
$zipOutPath = "Z:\long folder path\Test Folder\Unzip Test\Unzip"
$zipFilePassword = "TEST123"

Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFolderRoot -Exclude Unzip -Directory

Foreach ($zipFolderChild in (Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFolderRoot -Exclude Unzip))
{
    $zipFile = "$zipFolderChild\Data.zip" 
    $command = "x", "$zipFile", "-p$zipFilePassword", "-y", "-o$zipOutPath"
    & $7ZipPath @command
    #file rename command that I have not written yet
}
```

I used [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) for `$command`.

Edit: some examples for OP second question.

Try both examples and see what happens.

First:

```
$i = 0
Foreach ($zipFolderChild in (Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFolderRoot -Exclude Unzip))
{
    $zipFolderChild.name
    Write-Output "step"
}
```

Second:

```
$i = 0
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFolderRoot -Exclude Unzip
Foreach ($zipFolderChild in $folder)
{      
    $folder[$i].name
    Write-Output $i
    $i++
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works for me. Here comes my 2nd question. How do I get the "ChildFolder" Name?  in the code, it seems like the `$zipFolderChild` is the full path. But I want:

    Data.xls from 20181001 rename to 20181001.xls
    Data.xls from 20181008 rename to 20181008.xls

Sorry for asking you guys such novice questions, this is my first time ever writing Powershell Scripts and the documentations I googled are too overwhelming.

Comment: The best way is to assign `Get-ChildItem` to variable and then refer to its value, for example: `$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFolderRoot -Exclude Unzip -Directory`. By using `$folder.name` you're gonna get array of folder names. You can refer to each one of them: `$folder[0].name`

Comment: OK, but then the `[0]` etc will be a variable, meaning I need to get that inside the loop and use a counter e.g. `i=0` and `i=i+1` etc. to get that work. Am I right?

Comment: You can just use `$zipFolderChild.name` inside `Foreach` loop for the current folder name. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, actually, even when using your code, the loop has looped twice for the folder `20181008`, but never extracted anything from `20181001`

Comment: I made a mistake while copying. See edit. IIRC inside your `.zip` files is file with the same name. If you extract it to the same folder, it will overwrite previous file, while using `-y` paramter. When `-y` is deleted, you will get promped if you want to overwrite.

Comment: tried the following:
`$folder= $zipFolderChild.Name
    $xlsFile = "$zipOutPath\Data.xls"
    $NewName = "$zipOutPath\$folder.xls"
    $rename = "-path", "$xlsFile" ,"-NewName", "$NewName"
    & Rename-Item @rename`

got errors saying `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-NewName'.`

Comment: OK, I run that directly
`& Rename-Item @rename` and it works now.  **So** I was not doing the splatting correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work better?

```
& $7ZipPath x -o$zipOutPath -y -p$zipFilePassword $zipFile
```

$zipFile won't get the variables with single quotes:

```
 $zipFile = "$zipFolderChild" + "\" + "Data.zip"
```

Comment: Sadly not. Removing the single quote in the command line generates error. Coz the full path contains spaces.

Comment: Spaces in the path work for me.  I'm saying don't use iex at all.  Just run &.

Comment: Not working either, throwing loads of red errors to me

Comment: Take the single quotes out of the $zipFile = line.

Comment: Sadly, still not working.  It doesn't like the $7ZipPath when I run directly, with or without quote marks.

Comment: You can always just run C:\7z\7za.exe.  You don't need & with rename-item.